# Laravel Adldab2 - Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, ldap

I have medium size application I have built using laravel, now I am asked to do ldap integration so all the users are in ldap are registered automatically. I found the adldab2 package the most suitable way and I was following [this](https://adldap2.github.io/Adldap2-Laravel/#/auth/introduction) document, but I have not achieved or managed to make it work .. so is there is anything missing from the document? and is there is any other way to integrate ldap ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm with the same trouble. [Maybe this guide](https://github.com/jotaelesalinas/laravel-simple-ldap-auth) can help you.

Good luck.